# find in text file names, preg_match_all

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

i want to find in text file names (ex. name.txt).
Could you please suggest me the regex expression to use in preg_match_all()?
I create some regex expression:

> preg_match_all("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}$/", $string, $w);

But, always get an empty result.

Comment: I think that you should use the delimiters `^'  and `$` because I guess you 're doing the `preg_match_all` to a text or sentence.

Answer (score 0):

just delete these symbols (^ and $) in you reg expression

This works for me:

```
preg_match_all("![a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}!", $string, $w);
```

^ - Matches the beginning of the string.

$ - Matches the end of the string.

If you file is placed in the text you can omit this symbols.

I'd use the following reg expression, because the  one you wrote finds the files with extension composed of 1 to 3 letters, but usually the extension contains 3 letters(.doc, txt)

Here is the working example:

```
$string=" some text name.txt  some text hello.doc";
preg_match_all("![a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}!", $string, $w);
print_r($w);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => name.txt ) )
```